# How to change the background image (e.g. of a grid or main page)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

OK, I'm not interested in changing the background to some solid color.

What I'm interested in is to change the background to some image (like : http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/grocery-gadget/3dde9cca-a5c8-4ddd-831f-460c545b10a9 -- check the screenshots, to see what I mean)

- How is this doable?
- What should I take care of so that dimensions/etc are fine, no matter what?

Any ideas?

Comment: That app is not changing the background image on a single page. It has multiple pages each with a different image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted to change the background of a grid control. So you need to set the background property of that control. Background property is of brush type. So define a brush like this

```
ImageBrush background = new ImageBrush
{
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/yourimage.jpg", UriKind.Relative)) , Stretch=Stretch.Uniform
};
```

set the image brush property and try for others. And now you name your grid control or whatever it may be and assign that control background to background image brush defined already like

```
LayoutRoot.Background=background;
```

I hope this made you clear. Get to me if this isn't intended.

Comment: Buddy, thanks a lot! I had tried so many different things and all I had managed was to over-complicate the issue. Your solution (even via XAML only, no code at all) simply worked. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I suppose you are mistaken. This is c# code which can be written in the necessary event you want. xaml would be something like <Grid Name="LayoutGrid" >
 <Grid.Background ImageSource="/Images/back.jpg"/>

Comment: That's exactly what I did (what you talk about in your comment). :-)